# django coverage fails to include most py files

Tags: django, coverage.py, cookiecutter-django

I have run coverage on a project that I set up with cookie cutter for django.  In the report, coverage includes the py files in the user app that cookie cutter set up for me, and includes my html templates, but does not include any of my py files.

I want coverage to include my several py files under each of my 6 apps. 
 What must I do?

I attach a screen shot of my coverage report.

[image: screen shot of coverage report]

The percentages are not bad, but my numerous .py files are not on the report.

I am using the (lightly modified) test settings file that cookie cutter generated for me, to whit:

```
from .base import *  # noqa


# DEBUG
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Turn debug off so tests run faster
DEBUG = False
# coverage throws error unless the following is set to True
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['debug'] = True

# SECRET CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
# Note: This key only used for development and testing.
SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', default='CHANGEME!!!')

# Mail settings
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

# In-memory email backend stores messages in django.core.mail.outbox
# for unit testing purposes
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'

# CACHING
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Speed advantages of in-memory caching without having to run Memcached
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': ''
    }
}

# TESTING
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'


# PASSWORD HASHING
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use fast password hasher so tests run faster
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
]

# TEMPLATE LOADERS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Keep templates in memory so tests run faster
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['loaders'] = [
    ['django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    ], ],
]
```

To run coverage, here is my shell command:

> coverage run manage.py test --settings=config.settings.test

When I run python manage.py test, the output shows 65 tests.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are the missing .py files located in your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

I got all the apps on the report by deleting .coverage and .coveragerc (actually moving .coverage to /tmp) and running coverage with each app on the shell command line.

But that put too much on the report, including site-packages!

I moved .coveragerc back, and edited it to include want I wanted (all my apps) and exclude what I did not want (like site-packages).

The report is now satisfactory.